# java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, exception, mapper, reducers

```
 public class PrimeMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,IntWritable,IntWritable,NullWritable>
    {
         public void map(LongWritable k,IntWritable val,Context c) throws IOException, InterruptedException
            {
                 int v=val.get();
                 int i=2;
                 if(v==1)
                 c.write(new IntWritable(v), NullWritable.get());
                 for(i=2;i<v;i++)
                     {
                         if(v%i==0)
                         break;
                     }
                 if(v==i)
                 c.write(new IntWritable(v),NullWritable.get());
            }
   }
```

when i am trying to run this code i getting error of typecasting error .

[image]

Comment: Post stack trace and specify which line throws exception.

Comment: add stack trace please

Comment: int v=val.get(); this line is error

Comment: Do not post or link to screenshots of text. Copy and paste the text into the question itself. (Note that error code should also be formatted as code.)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the default input format which is [TextInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html) (extends `FileInputFormat<LongWritable, Text>`), the mapper expects `LongWritable` as `key` and `Text` as `value`. If you haven't changed this explicitly in your program, your mapper definition is incorrect.

A correct implementation would look something like this:

```
public class PrimeMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,IntWritable,NullWritable>{
   public void map(LongWritable k,Text val,Context c) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
     int v=Integer.parseInt(val.toString().trim());
     int i=2;
     if(v==1)
     c.write(new IntWritable(v), NullWritable.get());
     for(i=2;i<v;i++)
         {
             if(v%i==0)
             break;
         }
     if(v==i)
     c.write(new IntWritable(v),NullWritable.get());
  }
}
```